# How to build a regular expression to parse comma separated values but ignore the comma with in the double quotes?

Tags: regex, perl, unix, expression

Example string:

```
2011-03-09,4919 1281 0410 9930,55107,SAZB2314,"John, Doe" ,1-888-888-4452 ext 1813
```

Need to mark all the commas but not the one within the double quotes.

Comment: Do not use a regular expression. Do not use a regular expression. Do not use a regular expression. Use a text parser.

Comment: But don't text parsers use regexes to break the input into tokens?

Comment: If you're trying to learn, do not use a text parser. 
If you're trying to be productive, do not use a regular expression.

Answer (score 17):

You could use [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) from CPAN.

Answer (score 10):

Or use [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS), which does the same thing but is faster.

Comment: It's not necessarily faster since Text::CSV causes Text::CSV_XS to be used if available. I do recommend using Text::CSV_XS, though, because it remove the extra complexity of using Text::CSv too, and you're guaranteed to get Text::CSV_XS over the slower Text::CSV_PP.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Data::Record](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aRecord).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a regex and not a proper parser like @eugene y suggests, here is one attempt.  The captures should return the list elements in order.

```
(?:(?:([^"]*?|".*?"),)*([^"]*?|".*?"))?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @f = quotewords ',', 0, $_;
    for (@f) {
            s/^\s*|\s*$//g;
            s/^/"/ && s/$/"/ if /,/;
    }
    print join (",", @f), "\n";
}

__DATA__
2011-03-09,4919 1281 0410 9930,55107,SAZB2314,"John, Doe" ,1-888-888-4452 ext 1813
"ashish", "kumar", "test,1", "test2"
"foo", "b,ar", "msg1", "msg2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a project and this regular expression helped me for a csv file in exactly the same format.

`("([^"]*)",?)|(([^",]*),?)`

This will not work if a single record is randomly broken into multiple lines. I had this issue and solved it by ascertaining whether the count of non-empty matches was correct.

Answer (score -1):

I know how to do this in Java. Regular expressions might work different in PERL but let me show the idea. There is a union of 3 clauses.

```
// 1) select any quoted text before comma
// if it fails then
// 2) select any text before comma
// if it also fails then
// 3) select any text before end of the input

final String OR           = "|";
final String QUOTE        = "\"[\\s]*"; //with trailing whitespaces
final String NON_QUOTES   = "[^\"]*";
final String COMMA        = ",";
final String NON_COMMA    = "[^,]*"; 
final String NON_END      = "[^$]+"; 
final String END          = "$";

final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
QUOTE+NON_QUOTES+QUOTE+COMMA+
OR+
NON_COMMA+COMMA+
OR+
NON_END+END);
```

It will give you matches that unfortunately will be ended by comma except the last one. There is no capturing groups because it does not make sense to define them with the union clause like this.

Comment: Something like Regexp::Grammars, Parser::MGC or Parse::RecDescent would be the way to create Perl code equivalent to this.  But for CSV, there are already modules that solve this problem.